# Critical section example with 2 processes

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, critical-section

```
 P0                                         P1
 ------                                    -------   
 do {                                      do {
      flag[0] = 1;                                flag[1] = 1;

      while(flag[1])                                while(flag[0])
      {                                               {

      }                                               }

      ( Critical Section )                           ( Critical Section )                          

      flag[0] = 0;                                   flag[1] = 0;

      ( Remainder Section)                           ( Remainder Section)

     }                                            }
        while(1);                                     while(1);
```

I want to check whether above code satisfies Mutual Exclusion , Progress, Deadlock  and Bounded Waiting or not ??

**Mutual Exclusion** : *It satisfies Mutual Exclusion.* because if they started concurrently , they will be trapped in "While" loop. So their sequence must be , one after another.

**Progress** :   As per my understanding Progress is , While checking condition for Critical Section , particular process should consider those process's which are interested in critical section, **other process should not be entertained.** In other words If there are 5 processes and 2 are not interested in gaining critical section again,  then , only remaining 3 processes ( which are interested ) should be considered in entering critical section. Now here,  After exiting , P0, from it's Remainder section , if P0 is not interested in executing again. Then P1 should not consider P0 while entering in critical section.But here P1 , is checking P0's flag to enter critical section. So violating rule. ***So No Progress.*** ( Is it correct thinking ??? )

**Deadlock** : If P0 and P1 executed simultaneously at the start , then both will stuck in While loop , so deadlock.

**Bounded Waiting** : ????

Above 3 thoughts are not matching with answer. Please correct me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theory of computing, not an actual program that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is reading the code *as it is*, not as *how it was meant (by the human who wrote it)*. So here's my interpretation:

**They won't be mutually exclusive.** Any halfway modern compiler might initialize a variable *at any point* prior to first read access. Thus, flag[0] and flag[1] might both be 1 right at the instant the program starts to run.

Furthermore, setting of flag[0] or flag[1] need not be atomic -- and it sure as hell doesn't ensure that the process notified of the change doesn't *overtake* the one that just set flag to 0. **Race conditions might occur, if remainder and critical part should not be run at the same time.**

I hope this is some kind of class assignment -- busy waiting with a loop is generally evil and should be avoided; there's mature schemes like semaphores, threads that can wait() and be notify()d and so on, so this is a "in a world that's even worse than ours" piece of code.

Comment: @ Marcus Muller : I had a same doubt about Mutually exclusive. But didnt pay attention as I want to learn concept rather than answer. So I tried to read what the human wrote :P ( Yes , it is difficult but still tried ) Anyway , can u consider it as Mutually exclusive and concentrate on remaining 3 thoughts ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the "Progress" paragraph. Could you re-phrase that?